# Reload a page manually

Tags: javascript, reload

How can I reload a page using javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location.reload()` Method: Reloads the current document

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript:

```
window.location = '';
```