# Nightwatch-friendly command or javascript function to reload a page

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload, magellan

I have been trying the various suggestions for reloading a page.

[Reload a page manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854296/reload-a-page-manually)

With Nightwatch magellan testarmada. The error I see is `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"`

Has anyone else run into this problem/ solved it?

EDIT: `client.navigate().refresh();` does not work.

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Answer (score 6):

Embarrassingly obvious, once I fixed it. I was calling it in an external function but the problem amounted to this:

```
module.exports = new Test({

    '@disabled': false,

    "test page that needs a reload" : function(client){
    client
        // set url
        .url(this.url)
        .pause(this.timeout)
        .navigate().refresh() // does not work
        .refresh() // does work. 

    },


});
```

Comment: I can't see why moving `.refresh()` to the next line would make any difference. Can you explain why it does make a difference?

Comment: .navigate() function was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Refrain yourself from using navigate here. Use the mentioned code below:

```
return client.refresh();
```